# Get scalar value from SELECT statement in stored proc, from within a stored proc

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I know the preferred method for returning scalar values from stored procs is either using `RETURN` or an `OUTPUT` parameter. But lets say that I have a stored proc that returns the value using a select statement:

```
CREATE PROC spReturnNumber AS

SELECT 1
```

Is it possible to get this value from within another stored proc?

```
CREATE PROC spCheckNumber AS

EXEC spReturnNumber -- <-- get the return value here?
```

**Clarification:** I need a solution that doesn't require using an `OUTPUT` parameter, or using `RETURN` to return the value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't use sql-server, so I can't answer specifically, but for PostgreSQL, the answer is **yes**.  I would imagine the same is true here... but It should be pretty easy to test. :)  In fact, probably easier than posting the question (assuming _you_ have access to sql-server)

Comment: Care to share how to do this in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [insert-exec](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#INSERTEXEC) to store the result of a stored procedure in a table:

```
declare @t table (col1 int)
insert @t exec spReturnNumber
return (select col1 from @t)
```

The definition of the table has to match the result set of the stored procedure.

Answer (score 6):

Use an `OUTPUT` parameter instead of (or in addition to, if this procedure is used by other applications) the `SELECT`.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.spReturnNumber
    @Number INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET @Number = 1;
    SELECT @Number;
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spCheckNumber
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Number INT;
    EXEC dbo.spReturnNumber @Number = @Number;
    SELECT @Number;
END
GO
```

If you can't change the original procedure, but you know its output will remain static, you could use a #temp table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spCheckNumber
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE #n(i INT);
    INSERT #n(i) EXEC dbo.spReturnNumber;

    DECLARE @Number INT;
    SELECT @Number = i FROM #n;
END
GO
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need a solution that does not require altering the source stored proc (`spReturnNumber`).  All it does is return the scalar using a `SELECT`.

Comment: You should state that as part of the question, since most of the suggestions you'll get *will* involve changing the source stored procedure. Dealing with this in the caller by using a #temp table or other means is much less efficient.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the first sentence covered that I had already considered using `OUTPUT` and `RETURN`.  But I updated the OP to clarify.

Comment: Irrelevant now for this question since you've already picked your answer, but in the future I still think you should state your requirement ("I can't change the source procedure") instead of how you think you will accomplish your requirement ("I don't want to use RETURN or OUTPUT"). If someone comes up with a different solution, x, that requires modifying the original procedure, would you update the question to say "I don't want RETURN or OUTPUT or x"?

Comment: Yeah, I see where I wasn't clear.  Are you saying I shouldn't have updated my question though? Sorry, not sure I see what you're saying I should have done differently (like I said, I see where I wasn't clear, so I was updating the question to make it clearer -- but other than that?)

Comment: I just don't think you made it clear in the right way. You should have just said "I can't update the source procedure."

Answer (score 4):

You can't get the SELECT value from "parent" procedure but you can get the return value like this:

```
CREATE PROC A AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ret int

    EXEC @ret = spReturnNumber

    RETURN @ret
END
```

Comment: Yes, you can only get the RETURN value, nothing else.

Comment: Yes, it only works when you `RETURN` the value, and you shouldn't use `RETURN` for data, only for error codes/status.

Answer (score 1):

If you are unable to change the proc being called .. place the result set in a temp table [or table variable]:

```
CREATE TABLE #results (val INT)
   DECLARE @someval int
   INSERT #results
     EXEC dbo.spCheckNumber 

   SELECT @someval =val from  #results
```