# TSQL Function returning results of EXECUTE @sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-function

I have settings table that contain various settings, eg:

```
|SettingOneID | AltSettingOneID | SettingTwoID | AltSettingTwoID | SettingThreeID | AltSettingThreeID | 
|------------ | --------------- | ------------ | --------------- | -------------- | ----------------- | 
|NULL         | NULL            | 1            | NULL            | 2              | 3                 |
```

I am attempting to create a function that will return a setting using the column names provided and a bool(bit) to check for a optional setting first or use default setting only,
if the optional setting is not available it will fall back to the default setting

I need to be able to provide the column names dynamically.

I am using SQL Server 2016 but need to support SQL Server 2012

The sql that works :

```
    DECLARE @TryOptionalSetting BIT = 1
    DECLARE @DefaultColumnName NVARCHAR(50) = 'SettingOneID';
    DECLARE @OptionalColumnName NVARCHAR(50) = 'AltSettingOneID';
    DECLARE @ID INT;
    DECLARE @settingId INT;
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000) = 
            N'DECLARE @ID INT; SELECT @ID =' + @OptionalColumnName + N' FROM [Settings] WHERE [ID] = 1 AND '+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(1), @TryOptionalSetting)+N' = 1;' +
            N'SELECT @ID = COALESCE(@ID,'+@DefaultColumnName+N')  FROM [Settings] WHERE [ID] = '+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(1), @TryOptionalSetting)+N'; SET @out = @ID';
    exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@out INT OUTPUT', @settingId OUTPUT

    SELECT @settingId
    GO
```

However, within a function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetMySetting(
    @DefaultColumnName NVARCHAR(50),
    @OptionalColumnName NVARCHAR(50),
    @TryOptionalSetting BIT
    )
    RETURNS INT
    WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @settingId INT;
        DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000) = 
                N'DECLARE @ID INT; SELECT @ID =' + @OptionalColumnName + N' FROM [Settings] WHERE [ID] = 1 AND '+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(1), @TryOptionalSetting)+N' = 1;' +
                N'SELECT @ID = COALESCE(@ID,'+@DefaultColumnName+N')  FROM [Settings] WHERE [ID] = '+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(1), @TryOptionalSetting)+N'; SET @out = @ID';
        exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@out INT OUTPUT', @settingId OUTPUT

        RETURN (@settingId);
    END;
GO
```

It produces the following error:

> Only functions and some extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function"

I attempted to use Temporary tables and Table-Value-Function including the removal of the `sp_executesql` with the following results:

> Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'INSERT EXEC' within a function.

Comment: You can't do this in a function. End of story. Functions cannot use `EXEC` commands (apart from a very few specific system procedures). Not be mention the above is open to injection. If you *must* use dynamic SQL it'll need to be in a Stored Procedure and made **secure**. Never concatenate unsanitised strings into a SQL query. **NEVER**.

Comment: @Larnu , yes this is a good point, especially about the possibility of sql injection. In my case, the function / stored procedure will not be subject to user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that in a function. You could use an OUTPUT parameter from an SP if you want to get a scalar result from the SP.

[Get scalar value from SELECT statement in stored proc, from within a stored proc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641113/get-scalar-value-from-select-statement-in-stored-proc-from-within-a-stored-proc)

Comment: The linked answer from Aaron Bertrand works, but I will try something more secure.

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedures in SQL are easier to create and functions have a more rigid structure and support less clauses and functionality.

The easiest way is to turn your Function into a Stored Procedure. Stored Procedures do not have this limitation.